# How does storm (with multiple worker nodes) guarantee message processing while reading from a kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, kafka-consumer-api

I have a storm setup that picks up messages from a kafka topic and processes and persists them.
I want to understand how storm gurantees message processing in such a scenario

Consider the below scenario: 
I have configured multiple supervisors+workers for a storm cluster.
The KafkaSpout is reading message from the topic and then passes on this a bolt. The bolt acks upon completion and the spout moves forward to the next message.

I have 2 supervisors running - each of which are running 3 workers each.
From what I understand - each of the worker on every supervisor is capable to processing a message.

So, at any given time 6 messages are being processed parallely in storm cluster.
what if the second message fails, either due to worker shutdown or due to supervisor shutdown.
the zookeeper is already pointing to the 7 message for the consumer group.
In such a scenario, how will the second message get processed?

Comment: http://storm.apache.org/documentation/Guaranteeing-message-processing.html , http://storm.apache.org/documentation/Trident-tutorial.html, http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2012/10/16/understanding-the-parallelism-of-a-storm-topology/

Comment: Thanks for the links but I have read those. Can you point out where they talk about the scenario I have mentioned

Comment: the messages never committed to zookeeper unless acknowledged .. the failed tuple will be replayed .. are you able to produce such scenario?

Comment: Am not reporting a bug. Wanted to understand how storm handles such scenarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is some miss understanding. The following claims seem to be wrong:

- The bolt acks upon completion and the spout moves forward to the next message.
- at any given time 6 messages are being processed parallely in storm cluster

=> A spout is not waiting for the acks; it fetches tuples over-and-over again with the maximum speed regardless of the processing speed of the bolts -- as long as new messages are available in Kafka. (Or did you limit the number of tuples in flight via `max.spout.pending`?). Thus, many messages are processed in parallel (even if only #executors are given to a UDF -- many other messages are buffered in internal Storm queues).

As far as I know (but I am not 100% sure), `KafkaSpout` "orders" the incoming acks and only move the offset if all consecutive acks are available -- ie, message 7 is not acked to Kafka if the Storm ack of message 6 is not there yet. Thus, `KafkaSpout` can re-emit message 6 if it fails. Re-call that Storm does not give any ordering guarantees.

Comment: What i understand is that spout keeps track of the messages ack'ed by bolt. So if 2 is not ack'ed it will be replayed to the bolt by the spout. Makes sense